# How can I package pack a service into a apk, without any other activity?

Tags: android, service, apk

I want to make a service run in its own process, and called through AIDL.

Most important, as a stand alone application, can be installed from a apk.

could I ? how to do it.

sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make apk files that only contain a Service with AIDL definitions as part of the package. Just don't include any Activity classes in the package.

Comment: Does Eclipse fail to pack it if you have no Activities?